# Which ginseng caffee should I order to get the experience of "Caffe al Ginseng" in Milano?

Tags: espresso

I visited Milano previous summer, I ordered "Caffe al Ginseng" in several places and I enjoyed a lot this coffee. Now I would like to order this kind of coffee on-line, but the shipping is quite expensive from Italy and there are too many options.

Can somebody propose me espresso ground coffees with ginseng extract or flavour to make Caffe al Ginseng at home?

I would like to "replicate" the same experience. It was pretty sweetish with strong flavour over the coffee taste.

Maybe this shop? http://www.persalute.it/p/64/eng/red-ginseng-coffee-ground-coffee-250g.aspx

Answer (score 4):

According to Italian wikipedia, the first ginseng coffee popularized in Italy was an instant packet drink also sold in Asia. [https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffè_al_ginseng](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caff%C3%A8_al_ginseng)
If you're willing to go instant, you can try this: http://www.veryasia.com/ginseng-coffee/ (also available on Amazon)

The wiki entry suggests what you drank was probably espresso with dry ground ginseng. So if you don't want instant, you could get some espresso and add dry ground ginseng to the grounds. You can get ground ginseng at any Chinese herbal store. One writer, Peter Lim says a capsule (like the gelatine type you would swallow) is the right amount for a serving of coffee.

Good luck.